# Tensorflow: huge loss function value output

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to implement [YOLO (You Only Look Once)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640v5.pdf) with Tensorflow.
But I write the loss function and train the network, the loss value is very huge like this:

```
2016-09-11 13:55:03.753679: step 0, loss = 3371113119744.00 (3.9 examples/sec; 2.548 sec/batch)  
2016-09-11 13:55:14.444871: step 10, loss = nan (19.8 examples/sec; 0.505 sec/batch)
```

The 0 step is already very huge and the others become nan value. 
I cannot figure it out what the reason is
Here is the loss function I write about YOLO:

```
def inference_loss(y_out, y_true):
'''
Args:
  y_true: Ground Truth output
  y_out: Predicted output
  The form of the ground truth vector is:
  ######################################
  ##1225 values in total: 7*7=49 cells 
  ##each cell vector has 25 values: bounding box (x,y,h,w), class one hot vector (p1,p2,...,p20), objectness score (0 or 1)##
  ##49 * 25 = 1225 
  ######################################

Returns:
  The loss caused by y_out
'''    
lambda_coor = 5
lambda_noobj = 0.5

box_loss = 0.0
score_loss = 0.0
class_loss = 0.0

for i in range(49):
    #the first bounding box
    y_out_box1 = y_out[:,i*30:i*30+4]
    #the second bounding box
    y_out_box2 = y_out[:,i*30+4:i*30+8]
    #ground truth bounding box
    y_true_box = y_true[:,i*25:i*25+4]
    #l2 loss of the predicted bounding box
    box_loss_piece = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true_box - y_out_box1), 1) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true_box - y_out_box2), 1)
    #bounding box loss
    box_loss_piece = box_loss_piece * lambda_coor * y_true[:,i*25+24]

    box_loss = box_loss + box_loss_piece 
    #predicted score
    y_out_score1 = y_out[:,i*30+8]
    y_out_score2 = y_out[:,i*30+9]
    #ground truth score
    y_true_score = y_true[:,i*25+24]
    #the first score
    score_loss1_piece = tf.square(y_true_score - y_out_score1) + tf.square(y_true_score - y_out_score2)
    #the second score
    score_loss2_piece = lambda_noobj * score_loss1_piece
    #score loss
    score_loss1_piece = score_loss1_piece * y_true[:,i*25+24]
    score_loss2_piece = score_loss2_piece * (1 - y_true[:,i*25+24]) 

    score_loss = score_loss + score_loss1_piece + score_loss2_piece
    #one hot predicted class vector and ground truth vector
    y_out_class = y_out[:,i*30+10:(i+1)*30]
    y_true_class = y_true[:,i*25+4:i*25+24]
    # class loss
    class_loss_piece = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true_class - y_out_class), 1)
    class_loss = class_loss + class_loss_piece * y_true[:,i*25+24]

#total loss of one batch
loss = tf.reduce_sum(box_loss+score_loss+class_loss, 0)
return loss
```

And this is the training code I wrote:

```
def train_test():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

        data_batch_generator = yolo_inputs.generate_batch_data(voclabelpath, imagenamefile, BATCH_NUM, sample_number=10000, iteration = 5000)

        training_image_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [BATCH_NUM, 448, 448, 3])
        training_label_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [BATCH_NUM, 1225])

        #inference and loss
        yolotinyinstance = yolo_tiny.YOLO()
        yolotinyinstance.build(training_image_batch)        
        net_out = yolotinyinstance.fc12

        loss = inference_loss(net_out, training_label_batch)          

        train_op = train(loss, global_step)

        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())

        summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        sess = tf.Session()
        sess.run(init)          

        summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(TRAIN_DIR, sess.graph)

        step = 0

        for x,y in data_batch_generator:
            start_time = time.time()

            _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict = {training_image_batch: x, 
                                     training_label_batch:y})
```

It confuses me for a while. Could anyone help?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your learning rate? This behavior can be observed when the learning rate is too high

Comment: Are you using normalized coordinates [0.0, 1.0]? YOLO and other single-shot methods normalize by image width and height which has the benefit of keeping losses, gradients, etc. in a workable range.

Comment: Thank you. The input image has been normalized to [-1, 1], I checked the output of network, the last layer output has been very huge, around 10e4. But for the first several conv layers, the output is not very huge, around 1e-1. I am checking what the problem is.